# FlexCard datatable: Restrict to only one selection and onrowselect update child flexCards

Tags: omnistudio

I have a FlexCard that:

- Gets invoice data from an external System (FlexCard Data source is an Integration Procedure)
- Displays the Invoice data in a datatable element
- Embeds two child flexCards: Invoice Charges & Invoice Adjustment Charges. I want to "feed" those child flexCards with the respective information of the selected invoice record.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to restrict the datatable so that only one row can be selected?
2. When an invoice row is selected, how can i update the child FlexCards with the "updated" datasource?

[image]